# Testing a custom crate

Tags: unit-testing, rust, rust-crates

I've got this crate  in`/src/lib.rs` which I'm trying to run tests on:

```
#![crate_type = "lib"]
#![crate_name = "mycrate"]

pub mod mycrate {
    pub struct Struct {
        field: i32,
    }

    impl Struct {
        pub fn new(n: i32) -> Struct {
            Struct { field: n }
        }
    }
}
```

The test file at `/tests/test.rs`:

```
extern crate mycrate;

use mycrate::*;

#[test]
fn test() {
    ...
}
```

Running `cargo test` gives this error:

```
tests/test.rs:3:5: 3:16 error: import `mycrate` conflicts with imported crate in this module (maybe you meant `use mycrate::*`?) [E0254]
tests/test.rs:3 use mycrate::*;
                     ^~~~~~~~~
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A crate is also automatically a module of its own name. So you do not need to specify a sub-module. Since you imported everything in the `mycrate` crate, you also imported the `mycrate::mycrate` module, which caused the naming conflict.

Simply change the contents of your `src/lib.rs` to

```
pub struct Struct {
    field: i32,
}

impl Struct {
    pub fn new(n: i32) -> Struct {
        Struct { field: n }
    }
}
```

There's also no need for the `crate_name` and `crate_type` attributes.